# Как закрыть браузер через python?

Tags: python-3.x, webbrowser

Я открываю сайт с помощью `webbrowser.open('https://google.com', new=0)` Далее мне нужно закрыть браузер. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Добавь описание: ОС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")
os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Контекста не хватает (по-любому используете библиотеку типа  http)
если метод `webbrowser.open()` на открытие, то метод `webbrowser.close()` закроет запущенные процесс.

Comment: пробовал, но библиотека webbrowser не содержит метод close()

Comment: я бы сказал, что эта либа https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/webbrowser.py с 2016 года без изменений...  и можно убить процесс, юзая `import os`    
`os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")`